# How do I find which table belongs to a single parameter(slug)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

There are 6 tables {Countries, Cities, Counties, Sectors, Positions, Working Types (Part-time, Full-Time)}
I'll link with the values in the tables above and list the listings.
For example:
London Jobs - domain.com/jobs/london
Part-Time Jobs - domain.com/jobs/part-time
Software Developer Jobs domain.com/jobs/software-developer
as
How can I do that using **Laravel**

```
$router->get('/jobs/{slug}', ['as' => 'jobs.list', 'uses' => 'JobController@index'])
        ->where('slug', '[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `slugs` table that contains all slugs and connection to which model and model id. `slugs` table with following fields:
`id`, `model_id`, `model`, `name`. In this case, you would have searched `slugs` table only and and get any other table according to `model` and `model_id`.